# Is `import type` equivalent to `import()`

Tags: typescript

Are

```
import type { Foo, Bar as Baz } from './'
```

and

```
type Foo = import('./').Foo
type Bar = import('./').Baz
```

equivalent?

Please be aware that the `import()` in this context is not a dynamic import but [`import` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#import-types) introduced in TypeScript 2.9. You can enter both examples into the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to verify that the syntax/types are valid.

I want to use `import type` but also create declarations for TS < 3.8.

If the above assertion is true I could apply an AST transform to the emitted declaration files.

Comment: Please be aware that these are not dynamic imports but an additional feature introduced in TypeScript 2.9: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#import-types

Comment: Ah interesting. That says these type imports are for non-module scripts that *can't* use normal imports, in which cases they wouldn't be interchangeable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are not equivalent, though they are often interchangeable in practice. There are two differences that can matter, depending on the context.

### `import type` makes a file a module.

The TypeScript compiler determines whether a TypeScript file’s top level scope is module-scoped or globally scoped (i.e., whether the file is a module or a script) by the presence of any `import` or `export` declarations. `import type` counts as an import declaration, so if it were the only import/export statement in the file, substituting a type alias for it would change the file from a module to a script. The practical implication of this is that if you have a file (usually a .d.ts file) that you *need* to be global, but want to reference types from a module, you’re stuck using `type Foo = import(...)`.

### `import type` can reference value and namespace meanings.

When you declare a type alias with `type Foo = import('./').Bar`, `Foo` is *purely* a type, even if `Bar` had both a type and a value meaning (e.g. `class Bar {}`). You have completely left the value side of `Bar` behind in this declaration. `import type` actually references the full `Bar` symbol and all its meanings, it just sets up a syntactic check that ensures you never use it in a position that would get emitted to JS (since the import statement will get erased in JS). This matters in a few places, easiest to show with an example:

```
import type { EventEmitter as EE1 } from "events";
type EE2 = import("events").EventEmitter;

// Ok, because `declare` means `Foo1` is not actually referenced
// in an emitting position.
declare class Derived1 extends EE1 {}

declare class Derived2 extends EE2 {}
//                             ^^^
// Error: 'EE2' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

type EventEmitterCtor1 = typeof EE1; // Ok
type EventEmitterCtor2 = typeof EE2;
//                              ^^^
// Error: 'EE2' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

const x = EE1;
//        ^^^
// Error: 'EE1' cannot be used as a value because it was imported using 'import type'

const y = EE2;
//        ^^^
// 'EE2' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

[(Playground link)](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=15#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAogNxQOxixGBhhSjgEMBnbLARjgF84AzKCEOAIhT0I0eAbgBQSVPQBMcALxxQkWAAo+AmEICUAOlwEiJMhTGiAJigDGAGypQ012nQAiFYHlNMUAD3L5TdLEYMZjNLGzs4BxpnV3cZb19-aWDRcWQ0PUJiUnIoAGEYaCZ5CRQINnoGMVLsdWyjfMKoGRL08ukTCwh8GngvOUrO7t64RAHAqWEgA)